# How to translate certain string from lib?

Tags: django, django-registration, django-i18n

django-registration is missing some translations for german.
See [github](https://github.com/ubernostrum/django-registration/blob/2.2/registration/locale/de/LC_MESSAGES/django.po) Search for "". Translations are were but "broken".

I don't want to fork or change localization files localy.
Is it possible to provide translation for some strings in my app/project?

Comment: Did my answer helped you someway? If so, mark it as accepted. That's a good practice in StackOverflow!

Answer (score 0):

You just mention the 2 methods that are candidates for the translation of a string. If you do not want to fork the project nor change the localized files then I believe there is no other way of translating it.

<del>Last resort method: Make an identical file of `django-registration` that includes the to-be-translated string and add translations there.</del>

IMO the only way is to fork the project, run `./manage.py makemessages` and voila! Translations are there. Another thing you can do is to try to contribute to this package by fork it first and then make a pull request! That's the beauty of open sourcing!

Comment: What does it mean "make and identical file"? identic to what? and where?

Comment: My apologies. Please, disregard the last resort option. The only way is to fork the project and make translations locally. Answer updated!

Comment: as mentoned in the question this is not an option for me

Comment: Then, my friend, I believe there is no other option. Thats the price you pay when using third-party packages. On the other hand, because I have been in your place with another package, I made a pull request to suggest the changes, they accepted them and now I'm not using my forked version, but the official one!